# Yii2 send using SMS

Tags: yii2, twilio

Hi i  using Twilio to send notification to sms...but i got this error..i already searching to fix this problem but not find a solution..

Error Message:

**Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException**

**SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain**

backend\config\main:

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'sms' => [
        'class' => 'darkunz\yii2sms\Twilio',
        'sid' => '**********'
        'token' => '********',
        'number' => '*********',
    ]
    ...
]
```

in controller:

```
Yii::$app->sms->send('+612345678910', 'Hi');
```

i hope anyone who knows can help me to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sounds like you might need to make sure your server has access to an updated bundle of CA certificates.  This issue is described in this Github issues thread:

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues/203

In addition to updating your CA certs, there are a few other suggestions to try in that thread.

Hope that helps.